# Xamarin Forms iOS - invoking Tabbed Page button from ContentView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I need a simulated behavior as if a Tabbed Page button is clicked from the Content Page. This button is in the ContentView.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may crate an event at ContentPage like:

```
public delegate void BtnClickDelegate(string parameter);
public event BtnClickDelegate TriggerEvent;
```

Then Subscribe this event in your TabbedPage: `pageOne.TriggerEvent += PageOne_TriggerEvent;`

When you trigger your event in the page `TriggerEvent(string ...)`, method in TabbedPage will fire.